SQL Server read-only SystemAdmin account
Is there a way to create a sysadmin like account with only read privilege's.
I know that you can give a lot of grants to an account like view server state, view any definition, view any database etc, etc.. but still than this user will not always return the same info as the real SA user.
In some system procedures there are checks implemented to see if you are sysadmin.
It would be handy to have an account that can do all what you can do with the SA account except modifying anything.
Is that possible?

you can't deny permission to a sysadmin (you can but it won't work), so you could try creating an account to which you can grant Read permission on all server, and then additional permissions (view server state, view definition, etc.). But those SPs that you mentioned, that have a checks, not sure if you can workaround those.

This question is similar to: How to prevent sysadmin server role from executing a stored procedure. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Exactly because of all the built-in hard-coded checks for the role name "sysadmin" this is not possible.
The security team at Microsoft will have to keep working on fixing all those permission checks and come up with individual permissions.
While I was working on that we managed to change quite a bunch of DBCC commands for proper checks, but there is still a lot left.
However, those commands are normally not the every day required ones. Therefore you should be able to go a long way with VIEW SERVER STATE, VIEW ANY DEFINITION and VIEW ANY USER SECURABLES.
